# Why I can't call this function for each array item?

Tags: javascript, function

I got these 2 arrays and I would like to have a function (randomize() in this case) to be applied to each of them by calling the function and outputing the result to the console. Currently the console.log returns undefined

```
const array1 = ['I want to','You want to'];
let newArray1 = array1
            .map(item => ({value: Math.random(), item:item}))
            .sort((a,b)=> a.value-b.value)
            .map(item => item.item)
            .slice(0,1);



const array2 = [' eat',' sleep '];
let newArray2 = array2
                .map(item => ({value: Math.random(), item:item}))
                .sort((a,b)=> a.value-b.value)
                .map(item => item.item)
                .slice(0,1);


randomize = (x) =>{
  x.map(item => ({value: Math.random(), item:item}))
  .sort((a,b)=> a.value-b.value)
  .map(item => item.item)
  .slice(0,1);

}
randomize(array2);


console.log(randomize(array2));
```

Comment: Where is `array3` defined?

Comment: Mark_M, I edited the code shortly after I posted. it should have been array2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the return statement in your randomize function

```
randomize = (x) =>{
  return x.map(item => ({value: Math.random(), item:item}))
  .sort((a,b)=> a.value-b.value)
  .map(item => item.item)
  .slice(0,1);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`randomize` is an arrow function with no return value. Either add a `return` statement or remove the curly braces to use the implicit `return` for arrow function's whose body only includes an expression.

```
const randomize = (x) => {
  return x.map(item => ({value: Math.random(), item:item}))
  .sort((a,b)=> a.value-b.value)
  .map(item => item.item)
  .slice(0,1);
}
```

or:

```
const randomize = (x) => 
  x.map(item => ({value: Math.random(), item:item}))
  .sort((a,b)=> a.value-b.value)
  .map(item => item.item)
  .slice(0,1)
;
```

Also, in case randomize hasn't been declared anywhere, I added the `const` keyword to avoid creating an implicit global.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing return in map function

const array2 = [' eat',' sleep '];

```
randomize = (x) =>{
  x.map(item => { return {value: Math.random(), item:item}})
  .sort((a,b)=> a.value-b.value)
  .map(item =>return  item.item)
  .slice(0,1);

}

randomize(array2);
```

Comment: adding unnecessary returns in the map functions will not make the containing function return a value.  the other provided solutions are correct.